# How can I automatically fix cd typos?

Tags: zsh, alias

I often type quickly and will mistype `cd ../` as `c d../`, and for some reason on most of the Linux servers I work on that gives about a 4-5 second delay before telling me it was wrong. Is there a way to alias `c` to `cd` and have it operate on the remainder of the input?

Comment: In zsh you can omit the `cd` completly. Just type `..` or `folder_name` and the rest ist done by `zsh`.

Comment: @finswimmer Only after `setopt auto_cd`. It's off by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put [`setopt auto_cd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTO_005fCD) in your `.zshrc` and just type `../`.

But if you really want to make `c` work as a near-`cd` that strips off a leading `d` from the first argument, you can make it a function:

```
function c {
  cd "${1#d}" "${@[2,#]}"
}
```

With some more work you could even make it do completion after the `d`. But I don't see the point. Just omit `cd` altogether.